# why cannot the parent read from child

Tags: c, unix, pipe

Here I get a problem about pipe.

If I write to pipe in parent and read from pipe in child like this:

```
if(pid == 0){
    char str1[100];
    close(mypipe[1]);
    read(mypipe[0], str1, 6);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    exit(0);
}
else{
    while(wait(&state) != pid);
    char str[] = "hello!";
    close(mypipe[0]);
    write(mypipe[1], str, strlen(str)+1);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    printf("pipe: %s\n", str);
}
```

then I can get the print "hello!".

But if I write in child and read in parent like this:

```
if(pid == 0){
    char str[] = "hello!";
    close(mypipe[0]);
    write(mypipe[1], str, strlen(str)+1);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    exit(0);
}
else{
    while(wait(&state) != pid);
    char str1[100];
    close(mypipe[1]);
    read(mypipe[0], str1, 6);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    printf("pipe: %s\n", str);
}
```

then it print nothing.

I really don't know why...

Comment: In the first example, nothing is printed in the read side, so you cannot know if the read side has actually received something. Your ptintf is in the write side.

Comment: Besides, the second example contains a mistake: `str` is not defined in this scope, but `str1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there are mistakes in your second example code (`str` is not defined in that scope), and although it's obvious that `Hello!` is printed in your first example code, because you have just defined a string with that content and print it, your second code, which you claim it doesn't work, actually works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int mypipe[2];
  int pid, state;

  pipe(mypipe);
  pid = fork();

  // Child writes, parent reads and prints
  if(pid == 0)
  {
    char str[] = "hello!";
    close(mypipe[0]);
    write(mypipe[1], str, strlen(str)+1);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
    char str1[100];
    while(wait(&state) != pid);
    close(mypipe[1]);
    read(mypipe[0], str1, 100); // you should read at least 7 bytes, not 6,
                                // in order to receive the trailing \0 byte.
    close(mypipe[0]);
    printf("pipe: %s\n", str1);
  }
}
```

The other way around would be:

```
  // Parent writes, child reads and prints
  if(pid != 0)
  {
    char str[] = "hello!";
    close(mypipe[0]);
    write(mypipe[1], str, strlen(str)+1);
    while(wait(&state) != pid); // ensure child has read the pipe
    close(mypipe[1]);           // now we can close it
    exit(0);
  }   
  else
  {
    char str1[100];
    close(mypipe[1]);
    read(mypipe[0], str1, 100);
    close(mypipe[0]);
    printf("pipe: %s\n", str1);
  }
```

Comment: The undefined 'str' is a mistake when editing. Now the code runs correctly on Ubuntu, but still prints nothing on UNIX V6. Maybe there is something wrong with the system function 'pipe()' of UNIX V6. Thank you so much !

Comment: Some pipe() implementations have one end read-only and one end write-only.  Check the return value from your write() calls, and if one fails use perror() to emit an error message.  That might tell you what's wrong.